# The right way to define a reverse comparer

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a simple reverse comparer defined as follows:

```
template <class T, class Compare>
class ReverseCompare
{
public:

    //The same as Container::value_type, for example std::shared_ptr<A>.
    using value_type = T;

    //The type of the key for heterogeneous lookup.
    using key_type = typename Compare::key_type;

    ReverseCompare(Compare comp = Compare()) : m_comp(std::move(comp))
    {
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const T& left, const T& right) const
    {
        return m_comp(right, left);
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const T& val, const key_type& id) const
    {
        return m_comp(id, val);
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const key_type& id, const T& val) const
    {
        return m_comp(val, id);
    }

    using is_transparent = void;

private:

    Compare m_comp;
};

template <class T, class Compare>
ReverseCompare<T, Compare> reverse_comparer(Compare comp)
{
    return ReverseCompare<T, Compare>(std::move(comp));
}
```

it assumes that its underlying comparer is transparent like this:

```
struct Comparator
{
    using is_transparent = std::true_type;

    bool operator()(const sw& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const { return lhs.getString() < rhs; }
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const sw& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs.getString(); }
    bool operator()(const sw& lhs, const sw& rhs) const { return lhs < rhs; }
};
```

but it would not compile if the underlying comparer is a simple lambda, for example:

```
void main()
{
    auto comp = [](const int& left, const int& right) -> bool
    {
        return left < right;
    };

    auto r_comp = reverse_comparer<int>(comp);

    return 1;
}
```

GCC error message:

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'class ReverseCompare<int, main()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)> >':
prog.cc:53:36:   required from here
prog.cc:12:11: error: no type named 'key_type' in 'struct main()::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>'
12 |     using key_type = typename Compare::key_type;
    |           ^~~~~~~~
```

what is the right way to fix this?

Should I define a separate class or there is a better way?

**EDIT1**

I need `key_type` because I have `CompositeCompare` that requires it:

```
template <class T, class ... Cs>
class CompositeCompare
{
public:

    //The same as Container::value_type, for example std::shared_ptr<A>.
    using value_type = T;

    //The type of the key for heterogeneous lookup.
    using key_type = std::tuple<typename std::decay_t<Cs>::key_type...>;

    //Can be used if all the comparers are default constructible.
    CompositeCompare() = default;
    
    //A template parameter pack cannot have a default argument.
    CompositeCompare(Cs... comp) : m_comps(std::move(comp) ...)
    {
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const T& left, const T& right) const
    {
        return Compare<0u>(left, right);
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const T& val, const key_type& id) const
    {
        return Compare<0u>(val, id);
    }

    constexpr bool operator()(const key_type& id, const T& val) const
    {
        return Compare<0u>(id, val);
    }

    using is_transparent = void;

private:

    using Tuple = std::tuple<std::decay_t<Cs>...>;

    template <std::size_t Index>
    bool Compare(const T& left, const T& right) const
    {
        if constexpr (Index == std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>)
        {
            static_cast<void>(left);
            static_cast<void>(right);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            auto& comp = std::get<Index>(m_comps);

            if (comp(left, right))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (comp(right, left))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Compare<Index + 1>(left, right);
        }
    }

    template <std::size_t Index>
    bool Compare(const T& left, const key_type& right_key) const
    {
        if constexpr (Index == std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>)
        {
            static_cast<void>(left);
            static_cast<void>(right_key);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            auto& comp = std::get<Index>(m_comps);

            auto right = std::get<Index>(right_key);

            if (comp(left, right))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (comp(right, left))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Compare<Index + 1>(left, right_key);
        }
    }

    template <std::size_t Index>
    bool Compare(const key_type& left_key, const T& right) const
    {
        if constexpr (Index == std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>)
        {
            static_cast<void>(left_key);
            static_cast<void>(right);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            auto& comp = std::get<Index>(m_comps);

            auto left = std::get<Index>(left_key);

            if (comp(left, right))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (comp(right, left))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return Compare<Index + 1>(left_key, right);
        }
    }

    Tuple m_comps;
};

template <class T, class ... Cs>
CompositeCompare<T, Cs ...> compose_comparers(Cs... comp)
{
    return CompositeCompare<T, Cs ...>(std::move(comp) ...);
}
```

`CompositeCompare` assumes all its underlying comparers are transparent, and if they are not it ideally should not be transparent. Its usage:

```
struct X
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
};

using ACompare = ...
using BCompare = ...

auto comp = compose_comparers<X>(ACompare(), BCompare());
```

Comment: Try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with error messages.

Comment: @康桓瑋 added GCC error message

Comment: FWIW you can make the class a lot simpler like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e5da8f54b71f685

Comment: @NathanOliver Should probably add `const`.

Comment: @Dmitriano Maybe just remove `key_type`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can't remove `key_type`, but probably I define it depending on if `is_transparent` is defined in underlying comparer.

Comment: Why can't you remove it? What requires it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need `key_type` because I have `CompositeCompare` that requires it, see EDIT1

Comment: *"because I have CompositeCompare that requires it"* But *why* does it require it? Can't you remove it from there too?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat provided full source code of `CompositeCompare`

Comment: Hmm. I don't entirely understand what's its purpose, but you should be able to accept arbitrary tuples of keys (instead of a fixed tuple type), making this 100% transparent. Use SFINAE to check whether your underlying comparators accept tuple elements or not.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat composite comparer has a tuple of comparers, so its key type is a tuple of that comparer keys, it is for doing heterogenous lookup `some_set.find(std::make_tuple(5, "b"))`

Comment: Yep, I understood this, but I'm having a hard time imagining a case where that would be useful.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat in my project I have a container of `struct Trade {int id; time_point t, decimal price; ...}` ordered by 't' and 'id'. To find a trade in the container I do `auto i = std::lower_bound(container.begin(), container.end(), std::make_tuple(given_date, given_id);, TradePointCompare());` where `TradePointCompare` is a composite comparer.